I have demosite module can i use it for frontend and backend both?
Could the demosite module be utilized for both frontend and backend operations after cloning? How would you structure it to manage UI (frontend) display and backend data processing effectively? What steps would you take to ensure seamless integration and functionality?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
